# Did the stable boy use the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

At the very end of *The Last Jedi*, a stable boy on Canto Bight, who was given a Resistance ring by Rose when she and Finn liberated the fathiers, stares up at the night sky with his broom in hand.  The boy in question is pictured below.

[image]

The spirit of the final scene seems to be that a new generation of the Resistance is arising because of the "spark" lit by the actions of Luke and the survivors of the Resistance at the mine on Crait.

Having watched the film twice now, I might swear that I saw the boy pull the broom to himself from the wall, from a slight distance.

Perhaps he applied his foot to the base of the broom to swing the top of it towards his hand.  But if he did, I didn't see it.

**Did the boy use a Force pull on the broom or was the scene more mundane than that?**

Comment: According to all TLJ reviews I've read, the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, he did. He never actually touches the broom. Whether he is conscious of this ability as "not normal" and his other abilities is actually is the question. There is also another answer around here that brings up how he was holding the broom similar to a lightsaber at the end of that scene as well; kind of foreshadowing (similar to the ?director's? comments and such) that while the Skywalker family has been key to the Light side and the Light side was on its last leg, there are others out there that will become pivotal in the future and the Light side is by no means going away...

Comment: @Odin1806 : A comment from Rian Johnson would make for a nice, authoritative answer.

Comment: Let me see what I can find...

Comment: Wow, cool I missed it but it totally makes sense.

Comment: From sister site [Did the young boy move the broom through the Force?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83649/did-the-young-boy-move-the-broom-through-the-force)

Comment: This was not meant as a shout-out to Star Wars Kid, was it?

Comment: It was fairly clear from the moment this kid was shown being treated poorly by the pathier trainer/owner/whatever-he-was out on the race track that he would become an important character. I kept expecting him to pop up and be important already, but I guess it won’t be until the next movie. The final scene with the broom was not exactly a surprise, more of a confirmation that he was indeed Force-sensitive, as expected.

Comment: That's a lot of spoilers and not many warnings.

Comment: One doesn't need to be a force-sensitive to predict that in the near-future people who didn't get the point will be wondering who his parents are.

Comment: @MatthewRock : Perhaps, but I think these minor details are a far cry from "Luke, I am your father" --- I don't think knowing that a stable boy was freed by Finn and Rose or that he wielded a broom are going to spoil this production.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[Temiri Blagg](http://www.starwars.com/databank/temiri-blagg) held his hand out and the broom traveled toward him. I think we can presume that he used the Force rather than it being some kind of high technology *hover-broom.*

[image]

Comment: What I wanted to rule out is that he stepped on the bottom of the broom to swing it towards his hand, as I mentioned in the question.  This clip, even though it's a little dark, shows that he was too far from the broom to do such a thing.  So I'll take this as verification.  Thanks.

Comment: @Praxis This is the quote I was referring to... Took a minute to find it! (I have like 20 new tabs open right now from scanning articles... haha) I will just add this onto V's answer: “...I think it’s something that’s gonna be necessary, that we’re pulling it away from the idea that [the main Star Wars saga] is limited to this small club of Skywalkers...”
— Rian Johnson on Rey's parentage

Comment: I watched that gif at least thirty times now but I don't see it. Maybe it's because I'm on my phone, but he just seems to reach for the broom exactly where it is standing.

Comment: @BennyBottema - He stands still and the broom moves. That's the entirety of the clip

Comment: @Valorum I see it it now on my laptop, but it definitely didn't look like it on my Galaxy S6. Now I know I thought the curtain was the broom :D

Comment: @BennyBotema - When the Bluray comes out, I'll replace the clip

Comment: +1 for hover-broom.  Although given that this occurs at a gambling facility that seemed to have a lot of very wealthy people in it, you'd think they could afford to have more reliable, longer-lasting, less use-the-force-and-rebel-and-make-you-loose-your-racing-animals droids do such menial chores.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy - Did you learn nothing from Phantom Menace? Slaves are cheaper than droids.